# Unity3D. Не отображается контент в Scroll View на Android

Tags: android, unity3d, android-scrollview, scrollview

Сделал сцену, где отображаются все уровни игры, для этого я сделал скрипт, где создаю список все сцен(уровней), которые заполняются через инспектор(https://prnt.sc/n96sy0).

Каждый элемент списка, это префаб, кнопка с текстом, текст - это название сцены.
Используется стандартный Scroll View (https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/scroll-view).

Проблема в том, что на андроиде не отображается список уровней, хотя в самом редакторе все норм. На 1 ом скрине, запущенная сцена.

Через Unity Remote все норм.

Вот скрин с телефона, там отображается только 1 дефолтный префаб - https://prnt.sc/n96x7k

Код, который запускается при загрузке сцены:

```
public class ListScenes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject viewLevel; //Префаб, который отображается в content
    public List<Object> scenes; //Список сцен
    private GameObject content; //Объект, в который будут добавляться префабы
    void Start() {
        content = Helper.FindInChildren(gameObject, "Content");

        addScenesToList();
    }

    private void addScenesToList() {
        foreach (Object scene in scenes) {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(viewLevel, content.transform); //Создаю префаб и кидаю его в content
            Helper.FindInChildren(obj, "Text").GetComponent<Text>().text = scene.name; //Ищу в своем префабе компонент Text и меняю текст на название сцені
            obj.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.name, LoadSceneMode.Single); }); //Вешаю свой обработчик нажатия
        }
    }
}
```

Версия Unity последняя.

Или возможно у кого то есть другие идеи, как вывести список уровней?

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: А при сборке apk эти сцены добавлены в окне "Build Settings"?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский конечно (http://prntscr.com/n98052)

Answer (score 1):

Без прямого назначения сцен имеется вот такой способ. В вашем случае вместо int i = 0 следует указать индекс первой сцены.

```
int count = SceneManager.sceneCount;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var scene = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(count);
    //Ваша логика работы со сценами
}
```

Поставьте дебаги внутрь вашего кода и посмотрите в консоль телефона при запуске игры, либо подключитесь к телефону через ваше редактор кода и поставьте брейк поинт на точку спауна кнопок - чтобы понять, что там не так.

Ещё одной частой проблемой "В редакторе всё норм, а на устройстве - нет" бывает непредсказуемость выполнения методов Start и Awake. Т.е. например, у вас есть два класса, один из которых в Start записывает себя куда-то, а второй в своём Start получает первый из места, куда он записался.

В редакторе такой код может спокойно работать, а вот на устройстве упадёт ошибка из-за того, что порядок вызова Start-ов поменяется. В любом случае, нужно сначала смотреть консоль приложения на телефоне.